# How to calculate mean of values from specified rows and order it in R?

Tags: r, sorting, mean

I have a set of data like `t(USArrests)`:

```
          Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut
Murder      13.2   10.0     8.1      8.8        9.0      7.9         3.3
Assault    236.0  263.0   294.0    190.0      276.0    204.0       110.0
UrbanPop    58.0   48.0    80.0     50.0       91.0     78.0        77.0
Rape        21.2   44.5    31.0     19.5       40.6     38.7        11.1
```

I would like to calculate the mean of `Murder` and `Assault` only for each state and sort the states from high to low based on their mean values.

I am new to R and am lost on how to do this. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: so you want the `mean(Murder, Assault)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the mean of `Murder` and `Assault` together (assuming this is the case since each state only have 1 obs for each), you could do:

```
sort(colMeans(df[c("Murder","Assault"),]), decreasing = T)
```

---

Or if your data is really untransposed use `rowMeans` instead:

```
sort(rowMeans(USArrests[,c("Murder","Assault")]), decreasing = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` is good solution for this. There is no need to `t()` the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
USArrests %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "State") %>% 
  # perform operations by row
  rowwise() %>% 
  # add a column with the mean
  mutate(Mean = mean(c(Murder, Assault))) %>% 
  # should ungroup after using rowwise()
  ungroup() %>% 
  # sort by Mean descending
  arrange(desc(Mean))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the **data.table** package:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(cbind(USArrests), State = row.names(USArrests))
mean_stats <- DT[, list(mean_murder = mean(Murder), 
                        mean_assault = mean(Assault)), by = State]
mean_stats[order(-mean_murder, -mean_assault)]
```

Here, I've ordered the results in decreasing order, first by mean murder rate and then by mean assault rate. However, as you can see, it is trivial to change that. Here is some sample output:

```
> head(mean_stats[order(-mean_murder, -mean_assault)])
            State mean_murder mean_assault
1:        Georgia        17.4          211
2:    Mississippi        16.1          259
3:        Florida        15.4          335
4:      Louisiana        15.4          249
5: South Carolina        14.4          279
6:        Alabama        13.2          236
```

If you are new to R, do yourself a favor and use the **data.table** package. Generally, it is fast for merging and aggregation and has a compact and understandable syntax.